# create python list of exactly three elements

Tags: python-3.x

is it possible to create a list of exact 3 elements?

I wan to create an list (or may be tuple) for exact the elements (coordinates in 3-d).
I can do it as:

```
nhat=input("Enter coordinate\n")
```

the problem is that it will take any number (even greater or less then 3).
But it will be good if I have it prompting for number if it is <3 and exit when 3 value is given.

**Edit**

what I am currently doing is:

```
 nhatx=input("Enter x-coordinate\n")
 nhaty=input("Enter y-coordinate\n")
 nhatz=input("Enter z-coordinate\n")
```

and then making the `nhat` list made of `nhat{x,y,z}`. Just thinking if I can define a list of predefined dimension, so that I don't need those `nhat{x}` variables

Comment: So input should be 3 or greater?

Comment: number of input should be 3, exactly....i.e. `len(nhat)=3` exact

Comment: So check the length before creating the list, and print an error message if it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
def get_coords():
    while True:
        s = input("Enter coordinates (x y z): ")
        try:
            x, y, z = map(float, s.split())
        except ValueError: # wrong number or can't be floats
            print("Invalid input format.")
        else:
            return x, y, z
```

Now your code becomes:

```
nhatx, nhaty, nhatz = get_coords() # unpack tuple
```

or

```
nhat = get_coords() # leave coords in tuple
```